# Firestore asynchronous API getting null values outside readData

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

[this is my logcat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3iap.png)

**I am trying to fetch data from Firestore and work on them [tried this but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301894/getting-null-string-from-inner-function-with-global-variable)**

> getting null value for "emergencyNumber" outside "readData()"
> I have tried this solution [Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301894/getting-null-string-from-inner-function-with-global-variable) but still getting null

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_contact);
        Log.d("TAG","Initial");
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        readData(new FirebaseCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String str) {
                emergencyNumber = str;
                //Toast.makeText(EmergencyContact.this, emergencyNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                phone = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.EmergencyContactNumber) ;
                //emergencyNumber = phone.getText().toString() + "Hello";
                phone.setText(emergencyNumber);
                Log.d("TAG",emergencyNumber+"inner read me");
            }

        });
 Log.d("TAG",emergencyNumber+"middle");
        Log.d("TAG",emergencyNumber+"end");
    }
    private void readData(FirebaseCallBack firebaseCallBack) {
        documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    long l = document.getLong("EmergencyContact");
                    emergencyNumber = "0" + Long.toString(l);
                    firebaseCallBack.onCallback(emergencyNumber);
                    //Toast.makeText(EmergencyContact.this, emergencyNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("TAG",emergencyNumber+"exit read me");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private interface FirebaseCallBack {
        void onCallback(String str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firestore asynchronous API getting null values outside readData.

Any code that needs data from Cloud Firestore needs to be inside the "onComplete()" method, or be called from there. It doesn't really matter if you create another callback, the same rules apply. This means that you cannot use the value of "emergencyNumber" outside the "onCallback()" method. Please note that this method fires, only when "onComplete()" method fires, hence that behavior. When the following Log statement is triggered:

```
Log.d("TAG",emergencyNumber+"middle");
```

The data isn't finished loading yet, that's why you have that order of execution in your logcat.

If you are not comfortable with callbacks, then I recommend you using the modern way of dealing with asynchronous programming when getting data from Firestore, which is using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). Here you can find an example from one of my [repositories](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication) where I have used the MVVM architecture pattern with LiveData and ViewModel to authenticate users in Firebase.

If you consider at some point in time to try using [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), please check below an example:

- https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreJetpackCompose

Where I have used [Kotlin Coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) for getting data from Firestore.